# Download zip file and trigger "save file" dialog from angular method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a standard angular code, that is triggered when button is clicked:

```
$scope.downloadAll = function () {   
  $http.get("download.php?id=" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
    }).error(function () {
        $scope.status = "Error: can not download table data from server.";
    }); 
 }
```

but my php script returns a zip archive and its contents thus ends up in javascript variable, **data**.  I would like to modify the behaviour so that the zip archive is offered by browser to store on local disk. How I would achieve that, keeping the angular button handler?

Comment: `window.location = "download.php?id=" + $scope.id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your angular controller, inject `$window` and use it like this:

```
$scope.downloadAll = function () {
  $window.location.href = "/download.php?id=" + $scope.id;
}
```

On the server, make sure that your zip file is served with the appropriate http headers to prompt a file download (content-disposition, mime type, ...).

Comment: Is there a way to specify the download filename? The same way you'd get with `<a download="filename.zip" href="/download.php?...">`, but without the anchor tag?

Comment: That's what the server headers are for (`content-disposition`)