# Dropbox SDK and forcing a download via filesDownloadZip

Tags: angular, dropbox, dropbox-sdk-js

Using the dropbox SDK for a client side angular project.  I'm able to call filesDownloadZip() but I'm not able to do anything with the result.

I'd like the browser to download the file with it's default behavior but I can't figure out how to "force" the browser to download the file.

Any ideas?

http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownloadZip__anchor

Here's the function call as it exists right now.  I'm not really sure what I need to do in order to force a download.

```
  filesDownloadZip(path){
    return dropboxSDK.filesDownloadZip({path:path}).then(x=>{
      console.log(x);
      console.log('downloaded')
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hello, it would be nice to know (a) what did you try?, (b) what did you get?, and (c) what were you expecting?. Any code would be essential.

Comment: try it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523621/7291379

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Download-Entire-Folder-as-ZIP/m-p/322776/highlight/true#M18971 ]

There's an example of handling download-style requests using the Dropbox API v2 JavaScript SDK here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/download/index.html#L52

(Getting the data from the `sharingGetSharedLinkFile` method works the same way as from the `filesDownloadZip` method.)

In short, you can get the data from the `fileBlob` property of the result, and then do whatever you wish with it, such as building a download button, as shown in the example.